# kafka sink connector creation for table having primary key as three columns

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a source jdbc connector for a table that has no primary key (table has column a,b,c,d,e) and it is part of an external database. I have the replica table in my database and I have created primary key using the columns a,b and c since those three combined together form unique data and can be used to form primary key. I am trying to create upsert sink connector and gave the pk.fields as a,b,c but when I launch the sink connector, it goes to degraded State and I am not able to see any proper error in the connect.log as well. I have given the pk.mode as record_value and in the pk.fields I gave it as a,b,c. Can someone please let me know if there is anything missing in the setup?

Note: it works if I change the mode to insert and remove the pk.fields. the pk.mode is record_value.

Update:

Hi Robin, Source table named as AccountDetails has columns accNumber, bankABA, bankOrigAccNumber, SpendingLimit and ExpirationDate and there is no primary key  for this table. The target table is AccountInformation and has the same columns but has the primary key as (accNumber, bankABA and bankOrigAccNumber) since we need to have primary key at target for using in a different application. I have created source connector which is working fine to pull the data once in 24 hours. I am trying to create a sink connector with the mode as upsert for pushing the data from topic to table and the primary key mode as record_value and primary key fields as "accNumber,bankABA,bankOrigAccNumber". When i launch the sink, it goes to degraded state.

Comment: Can you share an example of the message that you're trying to sink, and the two examples of configuration that you've tried?

Comment: Please add the logs of the connector process when it goes into "degraded state"- [mcve]

Comment: Sorry all. Could not update this thread due to other issues. We added primary keys on the table and used the primary key option to resolve the issue. Thanks for your suggestions and apologies for not updating this thread immediately